# jQuery .bind() one event overwrite the other

Tags: jquery

I have created this simple tool for selecting range of elements. http://jsfiddle.net/EnRfQ/2/
But It has a few problems.

1) I want the selected elements to be green. But why `prvni.nextUntil(druha).andSelf().add(druha).css("background-color", "green");` doesn't work when the starting and ending elements are the same?

2) Why the hover efect stops working after first click?

And naturally feel free to improve my code, if you have some ideas, because this is just a draft.

Have a nice day

EDIT:
I have run to one last( i hope) problem. http://jsfiddle.net/ejtrD/11/ when I move the mouse over some `div` nested in the `tr` , the hover effect stops working and I don't know why

EDIT no.2
Solved, I used mouseleave event instead and it works just fine, because it doesn't fire when moving the cursor to the nested element.

Comment: your fiddle includes jQuery 2.0 beta, `.andSelf` has been replaced with `.addBack` and `.bind` has been replaced with `.on`

Comment: what is the logic here, purpose of `stredI`

Comment: I am using the `stredI` variable to make sure that I am moving the proper end of the selected range. Like if the index of selected element is smaler than `stredI` then I want to move the upper end and for the other end likewise.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for `.addBack` but about the `.bind` I am using it because I need to bind the event only when it is activated by some button as in my example and I thought that this is not possible with `.on`

Comment: if you directly replace .bind with .on, it will work exactly the same as .bind.

Answer (score 1):

2nd problem is the following line

```
tabulka.find("tr").css("background-color", "white");
```

change it to

```
tabulka.find("tr").css("background-color", "");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EnRfQ/4/)